# HTML p tag equivalent except on the same line

Tags: html, block, inline

HTML `<p>` tags are, by definition, "block" elements, meaning each HTML `<p>` element occupies its own line. This is as opposed to "inline" elements, where more than 1 of these elements can occupy the same line. A `<p>` element's purpose is to enclose a "paragraph" of text, and it is one way to enclose text on an HTML page that is not inside other HTML elements, like `<input>` or `<cite>`. There are also ways to make `<p>` elements "inline." What I am wondering is, is there another way to enclose stray text on a web page that is "inline," as opposed to "block"?

Comment: What do you expect `<p>` to be beyond being a block element? What would it *mean* to be like `<p>` then?

Comment: I mean what `<p>` does, which is to hold "paragraphs" of text. That is what `<p>` stands for, I believe. There are other ways to do this, and you can technically just put text anywhere you feel like it, including outside the `<html>` tags, but this is not correct style. Unfortunately, there is not much that can truly replace `<p>` in this regard, which is why I opened it up to StackOverflow.

Comment: I am sorry if the question was confusing, and also that I finally edited it to be clearer after I picked an answer. I apologize to anyone who was offended by this, and may have had a better answer. I am new to StackOverflow, and forums in general.

Comment: it might have been better if you had explained what you wish to accomplish, instead of an assumed technical approach. If you have text on an HTML page, you don’t really need to wrap it inside *any* element (except that it will inevitably be inside the `body` element). Anything that really constitutes a paragraph should normally be marked up as `p`, and if you don’t like the default styling, you can write your own. There must be some real problem behind the question, but I just can’t see it.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that's not good "style" but there is no good "style." And I was assuming a technical approach because many people who comment on StackOverflow seem so technical, but now you mention it some don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what `<span>` is for.

Comment: but you have to aware that <span> has not any semantic value so it's not inline <p> equivalent (more <span> default style aren't the same as well), but it can be used as that. I think the better solution is to proper style <p>.

Comment: Can you really have text directly in a <span> element the way you can for a <p> element?

Comment: the question is not "can?" but "should?". And no, you shouldn't do that, the right way is to style p element. Of'course you can...

Comment: Thank you. Great answers from everyone. I guess the answer to my question is "not really, but there are ways around it."

Comment: I disagree @kAlmAcetA. Semantic value is important, but not always. Assigning EVERYTHING a semantic value isn't exactly appropriate, because some things don't need it. Semantic isn't universally better than non-semantic. As with everything in web design, it depends on context.

Comment: ' isn't exactly appropriate' what? Semantic is important not only it's good or by trend. It is valuable in SEO, WCAG (check results in screen readers <p> vs. <span>)

Comment: Semantic IS important, but it is NOT universally better. For example, some things need `<span>` tags, either for purely style or for Javascript hooks, but the content within the `<span>` tag has no semantic value. Similarly, `<i>` is seeing a resurrection these days as a placeholder for icons, because `<i>` has no semantic value (that's `<em>`'s job). There is definitely a place for simple layout-related code with no semantic value. Not EVERYTHING can or should be assigned a semantic value.

Comment: `Not EVERYTHING can or should be assigned a semantic value` I said that? No. However, I agree with your point, this question (and answer) is not `For example, some things ` it is exact and my comments are accroding to this not in general.

Comment: Without seeing the context of the code in question, it's really not possible to say whether a styled `<p>` or a `<span>` is the better solution. And, like everything, a good deal of intuition and opinion will go into the decision between `<span>` and `<p>`. I'm not here to argue, it seems like we're saying mostly the same thing, and have hopefully given @trysis something to think about and research. Handshake/high-five.